# Calling jquery document ready when the admin modal closes

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I've got some javascript which is run on document ready, but this is not called when changes are made in admin modals. How can I ensure these functions are called in apostrophe cms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Apostrophe's `ready` event:

```
apos.on('ready', function() {
  // Do it here
});
```

This event fires both on page load and when changes are made in admin modals.